# Should I install Vim or Neovim in a Docker image used on servers?

Tags: neovim

On my main machine Neovim is my go-to terminal editor. I find it much superior to Vim (I have also tweaked it a bit).

The fact is, I'm the only developer who will be connecting to the servers I talked about in the question, but there is a great chance that in 3 to 6 months I will be employing 2/3 developers that will work directly on the servers as part of their work.

If I knew for sure that I would be the only one using those servers, I would install Neovim **and** upload my configuration. But since I want to keep things simple and standard, I figured I would keep the text editor vanilla.

But the question still remains, should I use Vim or Neovim? I've been using standard Vim on the servers for now, as it's more widespread, but I'm pretty sure that Neovim would make Vim users feel right at home, while also providing a better experience.

Comment: I think you don't want to edit files in the container, you want to edit files on your host machine... thus...

Comment: Some would say to use a bare Vim since it is a server and a good workflow shouldn't involve developing directly on the server, some would say to use Vim or Neovim with a minimal configuration, you are thinking about using a Docker image which may or may not be a good idea depending on your particular situation... This is mainly a question of personal opinion which makes the question not really useful for future readers

Comment: I’m not going to edit code on those machines. But I have lots of configuration files read by my software. I need to edit them multiple times a day, differently on each server.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni then edit over ssh with netrw and you can use your own custom config